# When does tramp create a new connection for a process?

Tags: tramp

What/where is the logic that determines whether tramp reuses its current connection in order to execute a process or creates a new connection?

Is it as simple as spawning a process synchronously vs async?

Comment: I think connection re-use might depend on ssh ControlMaster? I feel like tramp pretty much made a new connection for *everything* when I wasn't using that. Until relatively recently it wasn't a default behaviour for tramp to use ControlMaster (previously you needed to use the `scpc` or `rsyncc` methods explicitly), and the feature also isn't available everywhere. I've seen the tramp maintainer answering questions here, though, so I suspect they might provide you with a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is sync vs async. Emacs offers two basic functions for creating a new process on a remote machine, `process-file` and `start-file-process`. The former function creates a new synchronous process (reusing an existing connection), and the latter function creates a new asynchronous process (opening a new connection).